# Firewall Block all outgoing connection

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-firewall

I want to block all outgoing connection. I have created a custom rule:

```
C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="blockout" dir="out" action="block" enable="no"

C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe advfirewall firewall set rule name="blockout" new enable="yes"
```

And it works, but only for web browsers, I would like to block other programs as well, for example Skype.

How can I do that? How can I override "white-listed" applications? Is it possible using only Windows Firewall Settings?

Comment: I just tested those two commands.. they don't just work for web browsers. they block more than that. i haven't tested it with skype.. Blocking a whitelisted application doesn't make much sense. You firewall is either a blacklist or a whitelist. It looks to me very much like by default with the windows 7 firewall, outbound connections are set to allow, which means it's set up for a blacklist, rules you add that block.. You can set outbound to block(or perhaps it's block all), then it's a whitelist - you create rules that allow.

Comment: You don't need to block something that you allowed and you don't allow something that you blocked.

Comment: You can disable the rule that whitelists the application. Maybe you can make a rule that contradicts another rule, so skype is whitelisted, makd another rule that blacklists it, experiment with putting that rule above or below. I haven't tried it but that's how you would do it though I don't see any point.

Comment: And by the way. Contrary to popular belief, you cannot block all with the win7 firewall. ARP still gets out.. you can see in wireshark that is getting out. And even some TCP and UDP get out oddly enough. And if you are quite effective at blocking all, then you won't get an IP Address(as DHCP gets blocked). I think that is possible with the win7 firewall.